# Using fabsf on CGFloats shows a warning

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

I'm trying to get the absolute value of a CGFloat parameter but I'm getting the following warning:

> Absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value

Comment: A CGFloat is a double on 64 bit platforms, but you're passing it to a function that expects a single precision float - use fabs instead here.

Comment: I just realized that and posted an answer to my question - thanks!

Comment: You can post it yourself and I'll accept that as the answer

Comment: Sure - comment now converted to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CGFloat` is a `double` on 64 bit platforms, but you're passing it to [fabsf](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/fabsf.3.html), which expects a single precision `float` - use [fabs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/fabsf.3.html) instead, which takes a `double` as an argument.